# How can I search in array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have databases with encrypted datas (name and surname). In my code I retrieves data to array and decrypt name and surname.

```
for ($i=0;$i<$pocet;$i++)
{
 $row= mysqli_fetch_array($vysledek);  
 $name = $c_hash->decrypt($row['name']);
 $surname = $c_hash->decrypt($row['surname']);
 $a_name['id']=$name;
 //echo $a_name['id'].' ';
 $a_surname['id']=$surname;
 //echo $a_surname['id'];
 //echo '<br />';
}
enter code here
```

But how can I do searching in this array? For example user want to find name = "John". 
Please, can smb help me or give me a advice?

Thanks M.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: If you want to search in database - just encrypt it and search.

Answer (score 0):

How about `array_search` or `in_array`?

[PHP Manual array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

[PHP Manual in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

please provide your full code.its not enough for understand your need.I guess you ask for code like this.

```
if (in_array("John", $a_name)) {
   echo "John found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to search within an array you can use in_array :

```
<?php
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
}
if (in_array("mac", $os)) {
    echo "Got mac";
}
?>
```

or if you want to search in associative array

```
<?php
$search_array = array('first' => 1, 'second' => 4);
if (array_key_exists('first', $search_array)) {
    echo "The 'first' element is in the array";
}
?>
```

and this one returns the first corresponding key of that value in the array

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
?>
```

hope these codes help you out